# HTML CSS - nav-tabs, data-toggle="tab"

Tags: html, css

I have a problem editing an HTML page. I need to change the content on the second tab on the nav-tabs, the one with the name Anexos. I tried to create a new href, but this didn't work. What do I need to do?

```
</div>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#adm_carteiras">Formulário</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#utilizacao">Anexos</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#utilizacao">Versões</a></li>

</ul>
<div class="tab-content">

  <div id="adm_carteiras" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="filtrar_cliente box" style="padding-bottom:25px;">
        <div class="box_conteudo">
        <div class="box_conteudo">
        <h1 class="title_box">Solicitação de Viagem</h1>


        <div class="adm_carteiras box">
          <div class="box_conteudo">

            <h4>Nome do Solicitante:</h4><br>


          </div> 
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? I don't get it.. simply change Anexos to something else?

Comment: Anexos is just the name of the tab, what I need to do is to put some content in this tab.

Comment: what are the libraries that you use ?, provide all the necessary code that you use, what you have given only partial and poorly copy pasted !, if you can provide a fiddle or codepen that would be easier for other to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the correct bootstrap nav-tabs structure

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```